# _myObject vs self.myObject

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, macos

When I was working on a game the other night, I realized that I could increase the performance of my "tick" code by decreasing the the number of method calls by using `_myObject` instead of `self.myObject`.

Assuming that `myObject` is a property, was implicitly synthesized by the compiler, and already has a value, will the bottom one do the same thing as the top one?

```
// Non-ARC
self.myObject = [self someValue];
_myObject = [self someValue];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those two lines are fundamentally different. The former is essentially a method call to the property's setter method, while the latter is a direct member assignment.

When you do something like `self.myObject = x`, that's typically the equivalent of method call of the form `[self setMyObject:x]` (although the actual setter method name can be something else if overridden in the property declaration).

In the case of a `retain` or `copy` property, there is obviously a lot more going on in that method than simple assignment. But even in the case of an `assign` property, there are major differences.

When you have a method call, there is always the possibility that the method could be overriden elsewhere in the code. In the case of a direct assignment, it's always an assignment and nothing else.

With the method call, you automatically have support for [Key-Value Observing](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html). With the direct assignment, no KVO notifications will be generated.

And finally, as you've noticed, there is obviously a significant performance difference between a direct member assignment and a call to a setter method.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. So for optimal performance, I should access `myObject` through `_myObject` (e.g. calling a method on the object), but I should use the `self.myObject` to set the value?

Comment: If performance is the primary concern for you then yes. Just bare in mind that you're losing a certain amount of extensibility and information hiding as a trade-off for that performance gain.

Comment: As a follow up, I needed to do some high performance code for a music app, and I did end up accessing the objects directly

Answer (score 4):

The answer depends on the declaration of the property: for example, if `myObject` is declared as `copy`, these two operations are very different: assignment through a property would make a copy, while assigning to variable directly would not copy. If the property is `assign` and `nonatomic`, though, the action they perform would be the same.

Comment: Things like atomicity can make a difference too, but in 95% of scenarios it won't make a difference.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Good point about `atomic`, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
//for @property (noatomic, retain) NSString* myObject, the setter generated by compiler after synthesize will be like this:
- (void) setMyObject: (NSString*) newObj
{
    NSString* temp = [newObj retain];
    [_myObject release];
    _myObject = temp;
}

//for @property (noatomic, copy) NSString* myObject, setter will be like this:
- (void) setMyObject: (NSString*) newObj
{
    NSString* temp = [newObj copy];
    [_myObject release];
    _myObject = temp;
}

//for @propert (noatomic, assign) NSString* myObject, setter will be like this:
- (void) setMyObject : (NSString*) newObj
{
    _myObj = newObj;
}
```

Hope this helps.